# How to pass a custom message to on_click method - jawax swing library in jython

Tags: java, swing, jython

I'm trying my hands at jawax swing library in jython. 
I'd like to display a custom message in the showMessageDialog of my on_click method but i'm not sure how i can pass the value from the main calling method instead of hard coding the message in the on_click method.

Here's the part of my code in question -

```
class MyWindow(JFrame):

    def __init__(self, title, checkMsg, infoMsg):
      ---Some code---
      self.button2 = JButton('NO', actionPerformed=self.on_click)
      self.button2.setPreferredSize(Dimension(80, 35))

    def on_click(self, widget):
      buttonVal = widget.getActionCommand()
      if buttonVal in('NO') :
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(None, someText)
```

In the showMessageDialog, 
i wanna pass the "someText" value from my **init** method, variable "infoMsg", where the click button is executed.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can't you just set `infoMsg` to `self.infoMsg` and pass this into the JOptionPane eg `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(None, self.infoMsg)`?

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply @copeg. That worked! As you know by now, i'm fairly new to these classes. :) Really appreciate your help.